# How to add the class name of Dynamically created HTML in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium

The below code is dynamically generated HTML. How can I read it by using class name and click on the `li` element?

I want to select "Pandharpur" from the list of cities below:

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui.-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" role="listbox" aria-activedescendant="ui-active-menuitem" style="z-index: 1; top: -1018.18px; left: 667px; display: block; position: relative; width: 201px;">
  <li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
    <a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Kumarganj</a>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
    <a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Bitkewadi</a>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
    <a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Imampur</a>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
    <a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Pandharpur</a>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
    <a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Malichinchora</a>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
    <a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Pimpri Nirmal</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you tell us which framework generated the code? Several frameworks, such as GWT, have debugging options with offer you greater control on generated code for testing purposes, such as Selenium tests.

Comment: Does it have to be by `class name`? You could easily find this element using `link_text` ie, `driver.findElement(By.linkText("Pandharpur")).click();`

Comment: @MarkRowlands: It depends. If the web application supports multi-language, using text would be bad practice. Adding class names would be the best solution in general.

Comment: @user1177636 I agree with you but since he claims that using the `classname` isn't working for him, I'm just offering an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'ui-menu-item')]/a[text()=\"Pandharpur\"]")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:
With the given DOM Structure we can derive the CSS Selector for Pandgarpur

```
css=li.ui-menu-item > a:contains('Pandharpur')
```

Step 2:

Perform the Method

```
driver.findElement(
    By.cssSelector("li.ui-menu-item > a:contains('Pandharpur')"))
      .click();
```

to click it.